# D3 pie and partition layout value error

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I'm trying to make a simple Pie chart as well as a sunburst chart using D3 library in Google App Engine.

I pull data from the cloud and create a csv out of it

```
  function generateGraph(){
    var selection = document.group_choice.group1;
    for(i=0; i<selection.length; i++){
      if(selection[i].checked == true)
        choice = selection[i].value}

    limit_percent = document.getElementById("limit_percent").value;
    if (isNaN(limit_percent)){
      limit_percent = 0;
      }        

    var chart = d3.select(".chart");
    //clearing old data
    chart.selectAll("*").remove();

    var margin = 50;
    var width = Math.round((window.outerWidth*(3/5))) + margin;
    var height = Math.round(window.outerHeight*(60/100));    
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    //starting new data
    chart=d3.select(".chart")    
    .attr("width", width + 3*margin)
    .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2+margin) + "," + (height/2+margin) + ")");

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return 1 });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius);

    var g = chart.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data_from_var))    
    .enter()
    .append("g")
//    .filter(function(d){return +d[choice]> (limit_percent/100) * d3.sum(d, function(leaves){return parseFloat(d[choice]);})})
    .attr("class","arc");    

    g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d["data"]["Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME"]); });

    g.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d["data"]["Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME"]; });

/*
    g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d["Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME"]; });
  */  
    //tooltip
    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "title");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "code");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "unfilled_impressions");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "ad_server_impressions");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "total_impressions");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "total_clicks");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "viewability_percentage");

    tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "cpm_cpc");

    g.on("mouseover", function(d){
    tooltip.select(".title").html(d["data"]["Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME"]);        
    tooltip.select(".code").html("Ad Unit Code: " + d["data"]["DimensionAttribute.AD_UNIT_CODE"]);
    tooltip.select(".unfilled_impressions").html("Unfilled Impressions: " + +d["data"]["Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_UNFILLED_IMPRESSIONS"]);
    tooltip.select(".ad_server_impressions").html("Ad Server Impressions: " + +d["data"]["Column.AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS"]);
    tooltip.select(".total_impressions").html("Total Impressions: " + +d["data"]["Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS"]);
    tooltip.select(".total_clicks").html("Total Clicks: " + +d["data"]["Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CLICKS"]);                
    tooltip.select(".cpm_cpc").html("CPM and CPC revenue: " + +d["data"]["Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE"]);
    tooltip.select(".viewability_percentage").html("Percentage Viewability: "+ +d["data"]["Column.TOTAL_ACTIVE_VIEW_VIEWABLE_IMPRESSIONS_RATE"]*100 + "%");    
    tooltip.style("display","block");
    });

    g.on("mousemove", function(){
    tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px")
    .style("left", (event.pageX+10)+"px");
    });

    g.on("mouseout", function(){
    tooltip.style("display","none");
    });
  }
```

But this is my result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5badezaqinpru8y/Screenshot%20from%202015-08-13%2002%3A47%3A00.png?dl=0

The exact same thing happens with the sunburst chart as well. Is there anything I'm wrong? (Is more info needed?)

EDIT: The CSV content is unfortunately confidentials, but let's say these are the columns
Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME  Dimension.AD_UNIT_ID    DimensionAttribute.AD_UNIT_CODE Column.AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS    Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_UNFILLED_IMPRESSIONS   Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS    Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CLICKS Column.TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE    Column.TOTAL_ACTIVE_VIEW_VIEWABLE_IMPRESSIONS_RATE

Comment: seems to me this is unrelated to appengine. add the csv content here and treat as a pure d3 question.

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Comment: Just edited and added the code.